# Maven-jetty-plugin, Jetty 8, Maven 2 - как правильно прописать этот плагин в pom.xml?

Tags: maven, плагин

У меня на проекте Maven 2 (на 3 пока не можем перейти).
Используется Jetty 8. У Maven есть плагин для Jetty.

Вопрос: будет ли работать плагин с таким сочетанием версий? (Maven 2 и Jetty 8)

У меня в pom.xml прописано:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.21</version>
    <configuration>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
      <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

При запуске mvn jetty:run выдаётся сообщение:
"The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jetty-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found"

Answer (score 1):

Выяснил. Версия была нужна та же, что и версия самого Jetty. Например "8.1.13.v20130916".